# How to construct a function that picks elements of the kind $\{-1,\{\}\}$?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

I am trying to do the following: Given the list `{{-1,{}},{2,{1,2}},{-7,{}},{a,{}}}`, I am trying to construct a function that throws out all elements with anything in the first position and an empty set in the second position. I tried:

```
z[x_] := Nothing /; (x[[1]] == _ \[And] x[[2]] == {})
z[x_] := x
```

And:

```
z[x_] := Nothing /; x = {_, {}}
z[x_] := x
```

But this doesn't work. I need to apply it in this way because I need to apply this function to a nested set with `MapAll`.Can you help me?

Comment: Instead of a function, you may do this using a pattern like: `list /. {_, {}} -> Nothing`

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[z]
z[{_, {}}] := Sequence[]
z[x_] := x

lst = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {}}, {a, {}}};

z /@ lst
```

> ```
> {{2, {1, 2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

For a nested set [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) seems to work fine.

```
lst2 = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2, {-1, {}}}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5, {6, {}}}}}}, {a, {}}};
```

then

```
lst2 /. {_, {}} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5}}}}}
> ```

#### OP

You may use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) with [`Except`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html).

With

```
lst = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {}}, {a, {}}};
```

then

```
Cases[lst, Except[{_, {}}]]
```

> ```
> {{2, {1, 2}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or `Cases[lst, {_, {__}}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {}}, {1, {}}, {0, {0, 0}}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[a, {{_, {}}}]
```

{{2, {1, 2}}, {0, {0, 0}}}

Using `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[{_, {}}] @ a
```

{{2, {1, 2}}, {0, {0, 0}}}

`DeleteCases` can also be used for deeply nested lists:

```
b = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2, {-1, {}}}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5, {6, {}}}}}}, {1, {}}};

DeleteCases[b, {_, {}}, -1]
```

{{2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5}}}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {}}, {1, {}}, {0, {0, 0}}};

b = {{-1, {}}, {2, {1, 2, {-1, {}}}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5, {6, {}}}}}}, {1, {}}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's examples and using `Replace` with `Depth`:

```
Replace[#, {_, {}} :> Nothing, {1, Depth[#]}] &@a

(*{{2, {1, 2}}, {0, {0, 0}}}*)

Replace[#, {_, {}} :> Nothing, {1, Depth[#]}] &@b

(*{{2, {1, 2}}, {-7, {{3, {4, 5}}}}}*)
```